# Whats the difference between the 2 url routes in Django?

Tags: django

In Django, we define url mapping in urls.py. Whats the difference between these two?

```
/app/kill/$
/app/kill$
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both very different urls. But for must users they will be expected to be the same so django has a nice feature for this: the APPEND_SLASH settings variable.
From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/):

> When set to True, if the request URL does not match any of the patterns in the URLconf and it doesn't end in a slash, an HTTP redirect is issued to the same URL with a slash appended.